# How i can embed my script into the image kafka-ui

Tags: docker, sh, docker-entrypoint, provectuslabs-kafka-ui

I took the Kafka UI image (provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.7.1):
https://hub.docker.com/layers/provectuslabs/kafka-ui/master/images/sha256-633606ca07677d1c4b9405c5df1b6f0087aa75b36528a17eed142d06f65d0881?context=explore

I want to execute my script before starting Kafka UI, but I get the error script not found.

```
FROM provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.7.1

# Secret for swarm
USER root
COPY script.sh /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/script.sh"]

CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "java --add-opens java.rmi/javax.rmi.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED  $JAVA_OPTS -jar kafka-ui-api.jar"]
```

Error: `exec /script.sh: no such file or directory`

I was able to do this trick with other images, for example with the image `bitnami/kafka`. But I can't figure out how to do it with this image `provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.7.1`.

ADDITION:
I don't want to store secrets in docker compose files, so I use docker swarm secrets. They are stored in /run/secrets/...
The secrets are stored in docker files, so I use the sh script to turn them into environment variables.
Code link: https://github.com/swarm-pack/swarm-sync/blob/master/env_secrets_expand.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

env_secret_expand() {
    var="$1"
    eval val=\$$var
    if secret_name=$(expr match "$val" "DOCKER-SECRET->\([^}]\+\)$"); then
        secret="${ENV_SECRETS_DIR}/${secret_name}"
        env_secret_debug "Secret file for $var: $secret"
        if [ -f "$secret" ]; then
            val=$(cat "${secret}")
            export "$var"="$val"
            env_secret_debug "Expanded variable: $var=$val"
        else
            env_secret_debug "Secret file does not exist! $secret"
        fi
    fi
}

env_secrets_expand() {
    for env_var in $(printenv | cut -f1 -d"=")
    do
        env_secret_expand $env_var
    done
}

env_secrets_expand
```

In order to be able to execute the bash script, I added the line to the docker file:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

In the logs I see that the bash script is running, but kafka-ui ignores these variables, instead using the templates that are specified in the docker compose:

```
  SPRING_SECURITY_USER_NAME: DOCKER-SECRET->kafka_ui_user
  SPRING_SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD: DOCKER-SECRET->kafka_ui_password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you want to run `script.sh` and then proceed with the normal startup of the base image. Try this:

```
FROM provectuslabs/kafka-ui:v0.7.1

USER root

COPY script.sh /script.sh

RUN chmod +x /script.sh

EXPOSE 8080

CMD /script.sh && java --add-opens java.rmi/javax.rmi.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED -jar kafka-ui-api.jar
```

In the screenshot below you can see the result of a simple `script.sh` that runs before the main Kafka UI job starts.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello, World!"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I couldn’t immediately understand what the problem was. I figured out the first errors and added to the question.

Comment: Aha! But now you seem to have changed the problem. The original issue was that you were getting the "no such file or directory" error. But now you have a problem with environment variables. This is really a separate issue and should be a separate question.